# Is it OK to typedef a struct, say A, which contains an iterator of list<A>?

Tags: c++, struct, stl, iterator, typedef

So my `typedef` is like:

```
typedef struct {
    B b;
    std::list<A>::iterator iter;
} A;
```

I know a self-referential pointer works, but not so sure about an iterator, although they are quite alike. Just want to make sure, thanks.

Comment: have you tried to compile your code... i think compiler will give very obvious  error..

Comment: You could have compiled the code in the time it took you to make a post here. Anyways, it doesn't work. Why not do `struct A { ... };`?

Comment: Yeah. `struct A { ... };` works. Just a heavy C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct { /*...*/ } A;
```

is vestigial C syntax. The C++ way to write this is

```
struct A { /* ... */ };
```

As for storing an iterator, it's not really clear why you have any confusion about this.

However, using iterators requires caution. Many operations can invalidate existing operators, for example:

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
std::vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin() + 1; // references 2
v.insert(v.begin() + 1, 0); // invalidates it
```

*storing* iterators is a sure-fire way to lead into a world of this kind of hurt.